# How to locate images within svg namespace using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape from this website the images of the characters located on the left side of the page. When I inspect one of them, this is what I get:

[image: Inspect Element here]

Can someone help me with getting the `href=/assets/agents/agent_name.webp`?

I don't need the image itself, I just need the agent name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To print the values of the ***href*** attributes you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("svg g.dxc-elements-axes-group > g.dxc-arg-elements g > svg image[href]")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("href")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='dxc-elements-axes-group']//*[name()='g' and @class='dxc-arg-elements']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='image'][@href]")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("href")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```